# Is an infinite union of subspaces spanned by indicator interval functions in L$^2$(0,1) dense?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In L$^2(0,1)$ we consider the subspaces S$_n$  spanned by indicator interval functions $\textbf{1}_{I_n^k}$ obtained by dividing the interval (0,1) in n subintervals $I_n^k = (k-1)/n, k/n], k = 1,..,n-1, I_n^n = ((n-1)/n, 1)$.

Given $n_0$ an fixed integer and building the subspaces  S$_n$ for $n  > n_0 $ by halving the support intervals of indicator functions, is the infinite union of such subspaces, $ \cup_{i=0}^\infty S_{2^in_0}$  dense in L$^2(0,1)$?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd think so, wouldn't you? :) Even if at some point in life we don't know all the proofs, we can know the _facts_. Here, we know that (as in most real-life situations) continuous functions are dense in $L^2$ on a compact set with a Borel measure. And, as in an easy version of Riemann integral theory, any "sufficient" collection of linear combinations of indicator functions of intervals is dense in an $L^2$ sense in the space of continuous functions. Proofs depend on your context.

Comment: You can try to show that no nonzero function is orthogonal to all functions $\textbf{1}_{I_n^k}.$